# Regex captures don't live as long as I think they should

Tags: string, reference, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a Rust function that takes a regex, and a string/str and returns a `HashMap` of all the named captures in that regex. Here's the code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use regex::Regex;

fn get_matches<'a>(line: &'a str, re: &Regex) -> HashMap<&'a str, &'a str> {
    let mut results = HashMap::new();

    match re.captures(line) {
        None => { return results; },
        Some(caps) => {
            for (name, value) in caps.iter_named() {
                if let Some(value) = value {
                    results.insert(name, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    results
}
```

And I get this compiler error (Rust 1.9.0):

```
error: `caps` does not live long enough
      for (name, value) in caps.iter_named() {
                           ^~~~
note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 6:79...
    fn get_matches<'a>(line: &'a str, re: &Regex) -> HashMap<&'a str, &'a str> {
        let mut results = HashMap::new();

        match re.captures(line) {
            None => { return results; },
            Some(caps) => {
    ...
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the match at 9:8
        match re.captures(line) {
            None => { return results; },
            Some(caps) => {
                for (name, value) in caps.iter_named() {
                    if let Some(value) = value {
                        results.insert(name, value);
        ...
```

However, I don't understand. [`regex::Regex::captures` return value has a lifetime of `'t`, which is the same lifetime as the string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures), in this case, that means `'a'`, the [`regex::Captures::iter_named` returned value also has the same lifetime of `'t`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.iter_named), which is `'a` in this case, and that means the [`(name, value)` for that thing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.SubCapturesNamed.html) should also be `'t`, which in this case is `'a`.

My function definition has a `HashMap` that uses that `'a` lifetime, so shouldn't it all Just Work(tm)? I think I understand why you can't use a local variable, unless you return it, but in this case, I'm using references which should live long enough, right?

I suppose I could `.clone()` everything to `String`, but I'm curious if I can write this with just references. Isn't that supposed to be more efficient? I'm a little new to Rust, so I'm trying to grok things and do things in a proper, advanced way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is right, but you forgot a detail:

> `regex::Regex::captures` return value has a lifetime of `'t`, which is the same lifetime as the string, in this case, that means `'a`, the `regex::Captures::iter_named`* returned value also has the same lifetime of `'t`, which is `'a` in this case, and that means the `(name, value)` for that thing should also be `'t`, which in this case is `'a`.

* `regex::Captures::iter_named` also requires a `&'t self`, that is, `&caps` must have lifetime `'t` (`'a` in this case).

Note that the compiler is not complaining about `results` but about `caps`. `regex::Regex::captures` returns `caps: Captures<'a>`, that means that caps holds something with lifetime `'a`. But to call `regex::Captures::iter_named` it is necessary to have a reference with lifetime `'a` (`iter_named` parameter is `&'a self = &'a Captures<'a>`). **Although `caps` holds something with lifetime `'a`, it does not have lifetime `'a`** (the lifetime is only the `Some` arm).

---

I don't know how `iter_named` handle capture with empty names, but here is an implementation that returns only named captures:

```
extern crate regex;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use regex::Regex;

fn get_matches<'a>(line: &'a str, re: &'a Regex) -> HashMap<&'a str, &'a str> {
    let mut results = HashMap::new();

    match re.captures(line) {
        None => {
            return results;
        }
        Some(caps) => {
            for name in re.capture_names() {
                if let Some(name) = name {
                    if let Some(value) = caps.name(name) {
                        results.insert(name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    results
}
```

This maybe slower than `iter_named`.

Comment: > `regex::Captures::iter_named` also requires a `&'t self`, that is, `&caps` must have lifetime `'t` (`'a`).
But [the `captures` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures) should return something with a lifetime of `'t`, right?

Comment: You may not have total answered my question about lifetimes, but you have solved the underlying problem. :)